# Efficient way to access multiple URLs using file_get_contents() if they are from same domain?

Tags: php, web-scraping, file-get-contents

The question title basically explains it all. I have to collect data from multiple pages of a single domain periodically.

I can use `file_get_contents()` in a loop but that will take a long time. Is there anything that I can do to speed up the process if all the pages are from a single domain?

Update: I am thinking something like not looking up the domain again and again etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really, file get contents is file get contents and a network request is a network request.  There are things you could do to speed it up but it's involved, such as downloading each file and then executing an independent (non-blocking) script to process them separately.  even with that though, there are resource limits on any computer as resources are not infinite.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix can I do something to not look up DNS again and again etc.? I am not sure if what I am saying is technically correct but I hope you understood what I meant.

Comment: `Unfortunately, the URLs need to be accessed sequentially. The data from previous result would be used in next iteration` Yep that is pretty much going to kill any chance of parallel or asynchronous processing.  You would have to save all the files, once they are saved then you can process them sequentially, that's about all you could do.  But it will add a lot of complexity for probably not much gain.

Comment: So I mean you could try something that downloads them all in parallel, puts them in a folder, then once they are all downloaded you process them sequentially, but I don't know how much time it will save it depends a lot on IO and network bandwidth.

Comment: _not look up DNS again and again etc._ The operating system will probably cache the server's IP address so it doesn't have to be resolved each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl_multi_init` or use threads assuming you don't need the results of the previous request to process the next one. That should speed up processing quite a bit.

Comment: didn't even think of that, haven't used `CURL` in a while.  while at least not outside of an API

Comment: Unfortunately, the URLs need to be accessed sequentially. The data from previous result would be used in next iteration.

Comment: What I think you can do in that situation is use `curl_multi_init` or threads to download all the pages you need to process and store them. Then you can process them sequentially by using what you stored. It will give you a speed boost anyway.